# Cannot find the class EntityMapper in Spring ElasticSearch Data

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, entity, noclassdeffounderror, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm making use of the spring elasticsearch data to create document, index and also to perform query related operations. I'm using the latest spring-data-elasticsearch=4.1.0-SNAPSHOT and Elastic restclient and transport client version = 7.6.2 as per the document specified by spring elasticsearch data. But i'm getting the below mentioned error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/EntityMapper
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

I looked upto into the docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model where they're telling that EntityMapper has been removed from 4.0.X. Then why this issue is occurring. Can you guys please help in resolving this issue. It's a blocker for me.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If so, which version?

Comment: Yes, i'm using spring boot version 2.2.6? i think this might be problem i guess

Comment: I saw the ElasticsearchDataConfiguration code in version 2.2.6 has EnityMapper bean.. May be i will try to update the spring boot version and check this out

Answer (score 2):

As per the mentioned reference, `EntityMapper` has been removed from version 4.0.X.

And you are using `4.1.0` - spring-data-elasticsearch=4.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Hence the issue occurred.

Refer this section - `Removal of the used Jackson Mapper`

I checked the dependencies:

Refer older version - [3.1.9](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.1.9.RELEASE/api/) - It has `EntityMapper`

Refer [4.1.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/api/) - `EntityMapper` is not there - it's removed.

Comment: Removal of the used Jackson Mapper says if we've created a custom bean to make of EntityMapper, you need to remove. But i'm not using any custom Bean. Can you please explain a in bit more detail

Comment: The problem was with the spring boot version. In 2.2.6 autoconfigure calls ElasticsearchDataConfiguration.java which is of version 2.2.6. This class has Entitymapper Bean. But the spring-data-elasticsearch=4.1.0-SNAPSHOT didn't had this. So i upgraded spring-boot version to 2.3.1. It solved the issue. Thank you @gibbs for the help

Comment: Glad, you solved it. Actually spring boot related information are missing in your question.